# Dapper orm Not closing oracle nclob on unbuffered stream .Query<T>

Tags: oracle, dapper

We are using an oracle nclob for one of the columns in our database, while doing a "buffered: false" select of 8 million rows we would always run out of memory.

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_databaseConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var result = connection.Query<ClassWithNClob>(query, param, buffered: false);

    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        //do something with element that has a nclob
    }
}
```

We got around this by using the default OracleDataReader and when we wanted to access the nclob we wrapped it with a using statement.  We would like to use Dapper for this as it would make the conversion much much simpler, but can't at this point.

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_databaseConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new OracleCommand(query,connection);    
    using (OracleDataReader oraReader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(oraReader.Read())
        {
            using(var blobStream = reader.GetOracleClob(2))
            {
                //something with bloblStream.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We believe this is a bug, but is there something we are just missing?

Comment: Can you be specific? What exactly **does** the class expose for this property? What is the member declaration?

Comment: In our situation we are setting it to a string.

public string Record { get; set; }

Comment: and that is in the `ClassWithNClob` example? Because I'm surprised that works *at all* - I would expect this to be erroring, or at least ending up with irrelevant strings (like the type name, from ToString()) - what is actually happening when you do this? (I can't check; not an Oracle user)

Comment: Yes it is that ClassWithNClob in the example, do you think that the fact that we are storing XML in that clob somehow allow it to work?  It definitely is outputting the correct XML for that row.

Comment: The problem is: I know next to nothing about Oracle and how the ADO.NET provider handles this scenario. Anything I can add would be speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper tries very hard not to need to know much about specific providers. I suspect in your case it is just doing to equivalent of:

```
obj.YourClobMember = reader.GetValue(8);
```

The problem here is that indeed, it will never be disposed by dapper. I would suggest that *in this scenario*, your best bet would be to have a cleanup method **that you call from your loop**, that checks whether the clob member is not null, and if so disposes is and assigns it to null. This could even be by making your row type `IDisposable`.

There might also be something possible involving a custom type handler, but the fact that the obvious type here might be `byte[]` makes it awkward, as that already has hard-nosed handling.